# Including libsimdpp in a CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, simd

I decided to use [libsimdpp](https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp) for vectorization of my C++ code. Problem is, there is next to no documentation on how to get started.

Í assumed inclusion would be simple given that it's also CMake based like the project I'm doing, so I just tried to copy over the directory and set the include path. Well, turns out this is not enough: You need to define the appropriate flags to specify which SIMD flavor you want to compile for. libsimdpp includes a CMake macro just for that and it works wonders. I'm not sure however how to get going from here and it feels like I'm working against CMake rather than with it by copying things around and deleting stuff.

Would anyone with a firm understanding of CMake set out to explain what to do in a step-by-step fashion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the `simdpp/test/CMakeLists.txt` file where the tests of libsimdpp are compiled. The relevant parts are these:

```
foreach(SRC ${TEST1_ARCH_SOURCES})
    simdpp_multiarch(TEST1_ARCH_GEN_SOURCES ${SRC} ${COMPILABLE_ARCHS})
endforeach()

add_executable(test1 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
    ${TEST1_SOURCES}
    ${TEST1_ARCH_GEN_SOURCES}
)
```

Basically, `TEST1_ARCH_SOURCES` contains the code that uses libsimdpp. `simdpp_multiarch` copies the sources around and sets appropriate compile flags for them, so that implementations for e.g. SSE2 and AVX2 can be linked into the same executable. Then these generated sources (`TEST1_ARCH_GEN_SOURCES`) are added into the executable.